# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. in UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I'm learning MVC and for creating Login and Register with Custom Existing Database I followed [this tutorial](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/) and created custom User Manager and Sign In Manager. It allowed me to register a user properly and users are saved in my db properly. But *password is saved as string without encryption as user* entered it and also while login CheckPasswordAsync returns *System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.* For Implementing UserPasswordStore I followed [this tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-implementation) 
code for my custom signinmanager and User store is

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<MyAppUser>
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<MyAppUser> store) : base(store) { }

    internal static CustomUserManager Create()
    {
        return new CustomUserManager(new CustomUserStore());
    }

    public override Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(MyAppUser user, string password)
    {
        return base.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
    }
}

public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<MyAppUser>, IUserPasswordStore<MyAppUser>
{
    private LearningDBContext database;

    public Task CreateAsync(MyAppUser user)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = userStore.Context as LearningDBContext;
            context.MyAppUsers.Add(user);
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            return context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch { }
        return Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    }

    #endregion


    #region Password Store Region
    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(MyAppUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.HasPasswordAsync(identityUser);
        setMyAppUser(user, identityUser);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private void setMyAppUser(MyAppUser user, IdentityUser identityUser)
    {
        user.Password = identityUser.PasswordHash;
        user.Id = identityUser.Id;
        user.UserName = identityUser.UserName;
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(MyAppUser user)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.GetPasswordHashAsync(identityUser);
        setMyAppUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }

    public Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(MyAppUser user)
    {
        var identityUser = ToIdentityUser(user);
        var task = userStore.HasPasswordAsync(identityUser);
        setMyAppUser(user, identityUser);
        return task;
    }

    private IdentityUser ToIdentityUser(MyAppUser user)
    {
        return new IdentityUser()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            PasswordHash = user.Password,
            UserName = user.UserName
        };
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and in controller I'm calling

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
```

I can't figure out the reason. Can anybody help?

Comment: Would you mind reducing the code to the minimum required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have edited the code so that only required parts are left. But while implementing it rest of functions will be generated automatically by Visual Studio.

Comment: @Rohit this "password is saved as string without encryption" makes me worried. Why do you do this? You get this error when password hasher expects password stored as hash in Base64 format, but instead of Base64 string you are giving it a plain text.

Comment: I'm not doing this intentionally. It gets saved automatically this way and reason for this may be that I'm not overriding GetHashAsync. I am not providing any custom implementation for hashing. I put this line  because I thought it maybe the reason for this error and looks like it is.

Comment: @Rohit Any reason to override default implementation? I don't see anything outstanding that differs from the default.

Comment: actually my target is to save data in custom tables and not default tables created AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and so. My requirement is to just use previously created database of users with this functionality. I was able to register user with this but could not authenticate him properly.

Comment: @Rohit for future reference if you want to reply to somebody - mention thier name with `@` in the start of the comment - they will get a notification, otherwise people will ignore you cause they'll never see your answer. With regard to your question - you are saving plain text as a password, avoiding hash. Step through your implementation and make sure you put hashed password in, not plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help from @trailmax I was able to solve this problem. I was saving password directly and as I was using default implementation without overriding system was checking for hashed password. So, I needed to either save hashed password or override CheckPassword method for checking manually. It works both ways.