# formatexception: the input is not a valid base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to log in with an email and password which are already registered in the database but this is what error I get

```
FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

Here is the line where it breaks:

```
   var result = await this._signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

More specifically - the model.Email (the emails) breaks it all!

EDIT:
The problem was indeed that the passwords weren't hashed when passed into the database: So in this line of code:

```
var result = await this._userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

The model.Password was missing and that is why it wasn't hashed when the User was created. Instead, I passed in the User object PasswordHash = Password and that is why the password was kept as plain text. What a big mistake!

Comment: See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610928/1220550. The SignInAsync seems to expect a **Base64 string containing the encoded Hash of the Password**. Either *give it that*, or *find a way so it no longer expects that*.

Comment: @PeterB thanks for the answer! I am indeed storing the password as password , (datatype Is password) and is not as plain text. I wonder what may be the cause